# Iframe hides styling of container

Tags: html, css, iframe, youtube, video-embedding

I am designing a site that has a semi-transparent container for the content, which is divided into two columns. My CSS:

```
#content {
  width: 80%; margin-left: 10%; margin-top: 25px; margin-bottom: 25px;
  background-color: rgba(256,256,256,.6); box-shadow: 0 0 6px}

#sidebox {
  width: 25%; padding-left: 2.5%; padding-right: 2.5%; float: right; 
  background-color: #FFF}

#main {
  width: 65%; padding-left: 2.5%; padding-right: 2.5%; float: left}
```

The HTML for embedding the video:

```
<div id="content">

  <div id="sidebox">...</div>

  <div id="main">
    <div class="post">
      <a name="song" />
      <p class="title">New song!</p>
      <p class="date">Posted January 16, 2013</p>
      <center>
  <iframe width="480" height="360"
     src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/tF7DQBlYQGM"
     frameborder="0" allowfullscreen style="margin-left: -3%" />
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I put some static stuff in the sidebox and then make news posts to the main div. If I embed a video in an iframe in main, then the semi-opaque background from content (as well as the drop-shadow) doesn't render. I found a lot of solutions geared towards what to do if you want to overlay a div on an iframe, but nothing about putting an iframe in a div container screwing up the styling of that container.

The website, which currently has the video embedded: http://physics.nyu.edu/~dzb212/music_index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed some strange behaviors arising from my use of `<a href="blah" />` kinds of statements in my HTML. I was under the impression that `<[stuff] />` was the same as `<[stuff]></[stuff]>`, and that it was just a convenient shorthand for an element that contained nothing else. However, I don't know if this is true, and I found that huge chunks of text were unexpectedly being moved into `<a>` elements. I therefore changed

```
<iframe width="480" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/tF7DQBlYQGM"
frameborder="0" allowfullscreen style="margin-left: -3%" />`
```

to

```
<iframe width="480" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/tF7DQBlYQGM"
frameborder="0" allowfullscreen style="margin-left: -3%"></iframe>
```

and all seems to be displaying correctly. I no longer even need `display: inline-block` in the content styling.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure of the reasoning behind it, but if you add display:inline-block to your content style it seems to work on my end

Comment: This almost works correctly. When I add that to the content style, the iframe seems to set in the container, but is actually removed from the flow of the document, so subsequent text or divs end up being placed under the iframe. I tried included a div with `clear: left` and `clear: both` immediately after the iframe, but neither seemed to do anything. I could of course just add a large top margin to force the flow to look right, but it's not an elegant solution.

Comment: Actually adding a top margin doesn't work for me. Once I place the video, it seems like all subsequent content disappears.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

html content :

```
<div id="content">
<p> content div </p>
 <div id="sidebox">...</div>
    <div id="main">
        <div class="post">
        <p> main div </p>
            <a name="song" />
            <p class="title">New song!</p>
            <p class="date">Posted January 16, 2013</p>
            <center>
                <iframe width="480" height="360"
                src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/tF7DQBlYQGM"
                frameborder="0" allowfullscreen style="margin-left: -3%" />
            </center>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: When I tried this, "content div" fell in the container, but the main div and sidebox were both below the container, rather than in it. My code also has a `<div style="clear: both" />` after the main and sidebox divs, so that the container will enclose both of them. That doesn't seem to be related, though, as it works fine when the video isn't included, and does nothing when the video is included.